# Please help on regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

im looking for a expression with regex 
the string has such pattern
first 4 digits are numbers starting with one "0",
then followed by "w000 or n000 or wd00 or nd00"
then 7 digits of any char including [a-z][0-9]

many thanks

Comment: Please use the `Tags` field correctly.

Comment: why visual-c++ and c# tags? and second you sould provide a few valid matches and a few invalid matches....

Comment: sorry, i accidentally added c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with:

```
0[0-9]{3}[wn][d0]0{2}[a-z0-9]{7}
```

Comment: Awkward though it feels, I think I like this one more than mine. Depending on the Regex engine, the `()`'s can mess with groups if you choose to use that functionality.

Comment: @Stargazer712 you can avoid mess in your regex using `?:`: `(?:w000|n000..)` - this group will be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty straightforward:

```
0[0-9]{3}(w000|n000|wd00|nd00)[a-z0-9]{7}
```

There are plenty of other ways you can represent this, but this should match the string you described.

Comment: I prefer this one to the other (@hsz's) simply for readability and clearness of intent (something regex doesn't usually lend itsself to).